# What is alternative of service?

Tags: android, android-service

I want create countdown timer in service but the service may killed by system or when user shutdown his phone, What is the best alternative to ensure the continuation of the count under any circumstances?

Comment: You must try [ForegroundService](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) or you can use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager?gclid=Cj0KCQjw1PSDBhDbARIsAPeTqrcKypv5nQ1pKKygciZbuhMkwXKOnmDJkKPQRI2Nn_pk4MiKGrkQHLoaAuJcEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds&authuser=2)

Comment: I think we can save the count time and the time that your app turn off in sharepreference. So when the user open the app again, you can continue count at the point that the app stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  There's no way in Android to prevent yourself from being killed when in the background.  For a semi-long notification period, you can use an alarm.  These do have limitations on how frequently they can fire, particularly when the screen is off.  If you need it to go off more frequently than that, you probably need to redesign how your app works.

Answer (score 0):

You may take [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) into consideration rather than background service.

The system is less likely to kill foreground services on low memory/battery; and therefore it adds a notification on the task bar to grab user's attention for that.